# KnockoutJs - handling several areas with the same fields

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have several regions with repeatable content which is generated on the server-side. I use knockout-js to dynamically hide/show regions within areas. My markup is like the following:

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox"  data-bind="checked: a1" />
  <div data-bind="visible: a1">region0</div>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: a2" />
    <div data-bind="visible: a2">region1</div>
</div>
<script>
    var viewModel = {
        a1: ko.observable(false),
        a2: ko.observable(false)
    };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

Lets say I have 10 such regions. Is there a more convenient/better way to achieve the same?
Lets say, that I explicitly do not want to use `foreach` binding and generate markup on the client (for site to be accessible with disabled js).

Is there any way to omit viewModel specification (part within `script` tags), since it feels to me that knockout could detect and auto-create fields for me?

P.S. I'm a JS-novice, so excuse me for simple questions :)

Comment: You're pretty much misusing knockout.js here, so don't expect a simple solution.

Comment: Haven't thought about this.. seems you're right :) Is there anything more suitable for my case except plain js/jquery?

Comment: If your actual scenario isn't more complex, I'd go with a simple jQuery plugin. Shouldn't be much more than 4-5 lines of code. Or is there a reason not to use jQuery?

Comment: no, there's no reason against jquery, and things that I deal with are just a little bit more complex, than in the example. But omitting `<script>` part, knockoutjs can do this in almost 0 lines. And though this example could be rewritten as `onchange="$('#region1').toggle();"` which looks simpler, in a little more complex scenarios it becomes much less readable. So, I was trying to find a tool for a little-bit-more-complex scenarious :)

Comment: What kind of content is going in the inner div (the one that just has region(n) in it)? If your server is generating the code, you could also have the server generate the matching KO viewmodel.

Comment: I don't think it matters, but there are some inputs for user to fill-in :) And yes, at the moment it's server who is generating that viewmodel. But I'd be happy if there is a way to skip that part :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to omit viewModel specification (part within script tags), since it feels to me that knockout could detect and auto-create fields for me?

Although I prefer Knockout personally, you might want to take a look at [Angular](http://angularjs.org/). Angular does automatically create view model properties as [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/encmW/) shows.